# how to change result of a serch to friendly url

Tags: laravel, forms, seo

How can I change this URL generated from submitting the form

```
http://localhost:8000/list_entreprise?activity=3&sub_category=1&secteur=1&page=2
```

to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/list_entreprise/category_name/sub_category_name/secteur_name/2
```

Need to make the URL more friendly for search engines.

I get the **category**, **sub_category** and **secteur** from select fields in a form in

```
http://localhost:8000/list_entreprise
```

My route :

```
Route::get('/list_entreprise','App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@search')->name('search');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify these components in your route definition.

`Route::get('/list_entreprise/{list_entreprise}/{category_name}/{sub_category_name}/{secteur_name}/{page?}','App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@search')->name('search');`

Then be sure to add these as parameters to the `search` method in `SiteController`, i.e.

`public function search($listEnterprise, $categoryName, $subCategoryName, $secteurName, $page = null){}`

Notice the '?' after the `page` parameter, this indicates that it's an optional component of the URL.

Check out the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters.

When you specify the route for the action of the form, you will now need to add these parameters so it can build up the URL for you.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really answer your question. To substitute these values in to the form submission from select boxes, you would need a JavaScript solution, to take the values from the form and substitute them into the URL the form is submitting to.

Comment: Didn't work @Andy [ Missing required parameter for [Route: search]] but thank you, do you have idea how can i do it with Javascripor any other method